# Residue of $\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$ and $\ln(z^2+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have some trouble trying to find residue of both

$$\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$$

and

$$\ln(z^2+1)$$

First one, I am confused by get $0$ value at fraction value.
And second one, I don't know how to find residue of branch point.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ is an entire function, $z=0$ is a double pole of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$. Since
$$ \frac{e^z-1}{z}=1+\frac{z}{2}+O(z^2) \tag{1}$$
it follows that in a neighbourhood of the origin
$$ \frac{z}{e^z-1} = 1-\frac{z}{2}+O(z^2) \tag{2}$$
and
$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)},z=0\right)=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}\tag{3}.$$
In a similar way you may find the residues at the other singular points, that belong to $2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$.

The singularities of $g(z)=\log(1+z^2)$ are located at $z=\pm i$, but they are not poles.
However, $g'(z)$ has simple poles at that points.

Comment: Thank you for your contribute, dear downvoter.

Comment: I found this answer to be great. I wonder what the downvoter was thinking.

Comment: There are rogue, random downvoters. This site allows them and there's nothing, apparently, anyone can do about it. Besides $\;z=0\;$, $\;f(z)\;$ has (isolated) singularities also at the points $\; 2k\pi i\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$

Comment: How did you get question (2)? Could you please explain?

Comment: @BalasubramannyanS: $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}+O(z^2)}=1-\frac{z}{2}+O(z^2).$$

Comment: I know it's super late, but I didn't understand how $\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ help me to get the residue of $\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$. @JackD'Aurizio Could you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

In a very small neighborhood of $\;z_k:=2k\pi i\;,\;\;0\neq k\in\Bbb Z\;$ (for zero it already was done), and using the well known power series for the exponential function, we have

$$z(e^z-1)=(z-z_k)\overbrace{e^{z_k}}^{1}\left(e^{z-z_k}-1\right)+z_ke^{z_k}\left(e^{z-z_k}-1\right)=$$

$$=(z-z_k)\left((z-z_k)+\frac{(z-z_k)^2}2!+\ldots\right)+z_k\left((z-z_k)+\frac{(z-z_k)^2}2!+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=z_k(z-z_k)+\frac32(z-z_k)^2+\ldots\implies$$

and now use the geometric series development ( we can use it as follows for values close enough to $\;z_k\;$):$${}$$

$$\frac1{z(e^z-1)}=\frac1{z_k(z-z_k)}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac3{2z_k}(z-z_k)+\ldots}=$$

$$=\frac1{z_k(z-z_k)}\left(1-\frac3{2z_k}(z-z_k)+\frac9{4z_k^2}(z-z_k)^2+\ldots\right)=\frac1{z_k(z-z_k)}+\ldots\implies$$

$$\text{Res}\,(f)_{z=z_k}=\frac1{z_k}=\frac1{2k\pi i}=-\frac i{2k\pi}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain your "geometric series development"? Do you mean that since $1/(1-r)=1+r+r^2+...$ you set $r=-3/2z_k(z-z_k)+...$ and calculated $1+r+r^2+...$? Because if so I don't think your third term 9/4z_k(z-z_k)^2$ is correct.

Comment: @levitopher $$\frac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots\implies$$$$\frac1{1+\frac3{2z_k}(z-z_k)}=1-\frac3{2z_k}(z-z_k)+\left(\frac3{2z_k}(z-z_k)\right)^2-\ldots$$and$$\left(\frac3{2z_k}(z-z_k)\right)^2=\frac9{4z_k^2}(z-z_k)^2$$

Comment: I see, so you're just approximating the series in the denominator with the first two terms, according to your "very small neighborhood", $(z-z_k)<<z_k$.